# Connect to mysql 5.0 database using pure vbscript?

Tags: mysql, vbscript, odbc, mysql-connector

I've tried the below script but I am getting an error:

```
dim cn, rs

set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.connectionstring = "Provider=MysqlProv; Data Source=Adonis; User Id=mysqluser; Password = mysqlpass;"
cn.open
rs.open "select * from Countries", cn, 3
rs.MoveFirst
while not rs.eof
    wscript.echo rs(0)
    rs.next
wend
cn.close
wscript.echo "End of program"
```

Its giving the following error:

```
C:\mysql.vbs(6, 1) ADODB.Connection: Provider cannot be found. It may not be pro
perly installed.
```

When I googled for an odbc connector I came up to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html#win32) page where I could download the odbc 5.1 connector. Wondering if this is enough to connect to a mysql server 5.0 database...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and use a [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) like the following

```
connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=yourServerAddress;" & _
                   "Database=yourDataBase;User=yourUsername;" & _
                   "Password=yourPassword;"
```

Comment: no this does not work...I have installed the 5.1 connector correctly.

Comment: It worked. I'm sorry...my bad. Instead of "Driver" I typed "Provider".

Comment: will "load data local infile ......... " command works in the same code ?? please help me

Answer (score 2):

I made small changes to the above script and is working fine:

```vb
dim cn, rs

i = 0

set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;" & _
                   "Data Source=dsn_hb; Database=TP; User=root; Password=***;"

cn.Open connectionString
rs.open "select * from test.Login", cn, 3
rs.MoveFirst

'msgbox rs(0)'

while not rs.eof
    msgbox rs.Fields(0)
    rs.MoveNext
wend

cn.close

MsgBox "End of program"
```

Comment: variable i and variable connectionString are not defined