# Retrieve Data from SQL by Batch

Tags: mysql, batch-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883158/retrieve-sql-data-with-batch
Old topic is being closed because it's "unreadable".

Shortly. Is it possible to post/retrieve data to/from SQL database with any desktop-programming-languages like Batch or VBS and then, write the result to a file?

The only "theoretical" access we have is `%HomePath%\AppData\Local` and `H:\`
Our UAC access is `user`. I wish that user won't see anything.

Comment: If you have `mysql` installed, then you can write a batch file to use the CLI.

Comment: PRNDLDevelopmentStudios No, it's not Duplicate...
njk I am asking about, could you help me with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366516/connect-to-mysql-5-0-database-using-pure-vbscript How to write these data into a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the MySQL client from a batch file, vbs or anything else. If you download the MySQL zip package, you should be able to just unpack the client and run it from anywhere, to install/UAC required.

Comment: MySQL is too much resources taking and visible.