# Close program opened by vbs script with same script

Tags: vbscript

im looking for a simple code to add to this to exit the program

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe") 
wscript.sleep 2
wshshell.AppActivate "powershell"
wscript.sleep 145
wshshell.sendkeys"ipconfig /all > C:\Users\Public\file.txt"
wshshell.sendkeys"~"
wscript.sleep 300
wscript.sleep 145
wshshell.sendkeys"cls~"
```

Comment: What's your aim in this script ? Run Powershell and close it ?

Comment: sorry for my delay I had family emergency. yes that is my goal ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the `exit` command to powershell:

```
wshshell.sendkeys"exit~"
```

Comment: Instead of upvoting, could you mark it as the answer? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WshShell.Exec("powershell.exe")` instead of `WshShell.Run("powershell.exe")`.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set app = WshShell.Exec("powershell.exe") 
wscript.sleep 2
wshshell.AppActivate "powershell"
wscript.sleep 145
wshshell.sendkeys"ipconfig /all > C:\Users\Public\file.txt"
wshshell.sendkeys"~"
wscript.sleep 300 ' **** See note below *****
wscript.sleep 145
wshshell.sendkeys"cls~"
app.Terminate
```

`app.Terminate` would close your program.

**Note:**
`app.Terminate` won't wait for your tasks to complete before closing the application. With your code above it will close PowerShell even before it is fully loaded.

A quick workaround is to increase the sleep time.

```
wscript.sleep 300
```

A sleep time of 10000 is a safe guess for the powershell to load and ipconfig command to execute.

Comment: ty for your answer and the knowledge of this I tried upvoting your answer but it wont let me.

Comment: you seem realy good at this can I make a vbs script connect to a MySQL database?

Comment: user3802783 . Yes you can connect to MySQL database. That is a separate question though and should be asked as such, though you can use this code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366516/connect-to-mysql-5-0-database-using-pure-vbscript

Comment: I want to mark both of yalls answers correct lol. they both work flawlessly .