# What is the easiest way to check if I can connect to my SQL Database from another computer

Tags: sql-server, cmd, connect

Is there some easy cmd commands I can use to check if I can connect to my SQL Database Server? (windows computers).

Comment: Powershell, wsscript, ping server to see if it's reachable, use odbc administrator add a connection and see if it connects...  all methods which could check to see if server is reachable.

Comment: Well I would like to avoid installing any software that I can - Beacuse I won´t use these computers with the database later - so I would have to uninstall everything once I have checked it is working

Comment: all of the above are installed by default on windows computers (assuming supported versions)  Powershell example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682703/connect-to-sql-server-database-from-powershell wscript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366516/connect-to-mysql-5-0-database-using-pure-vbscript ODBC driver for sql server should be there by default as well...

Answer (score 3):

Open your Notepad and save your file as .udl
This is a Microsoft Data Link file extension. Double clik and enter your connection string. Click "Test Connection"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You create a new file on your desktop and save it as TestConnection.udl for example. Close your editor and double click on the file to fill the properties. Click "Test Connection".

Comment: How do I write such a string?

Answer (score 0):

If a client has not sqlcmd, you could make a telnet to SQL port, for example, 1433

Answer (score 0):

Posted this here originally: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/easy-way-to-check-connectivity-to-sql-server-from-client/306016#306016

There are so many ways to check connectivity - I got tired of googling every time I needed to check SQL connectivity from Windows, macOS, linux; to help with that, I created a docker image to test SQL connectivity.  It's very (very) basic and I will probably improve this overtime, but hopefully it saves people time.  Ok, so to test SQL connectivity simply run this command:

`docker run -it ssaadi/test-sql-conn`

It will ask you for host name, instance, port etc and then will try to connect and run `select @@servername` or display error if it fails.

The script is created in python and uses pymssql for sql connection -- the very very basic source code can be found here: https://github.com/sameersaadi/test-sql-conn